# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gis.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me to be a little bit of overenthusiasm from one specific moderator (who prefers to remain hidden) in this.  By responding individually to every post it really seems like they are guiding the result rather than it coming from the community.

Comment: So what if the current moderators did blatantly endorse particular candidates? They have that right (and you have the right to ignore it when voting). Anyway IMO the comments are pretty generic and congenially so far for multiple candidates - so I didn't take away that they were implicitly endorsing anyone (they have more nice comments than there are positions available - they have endorsed too many people to be effective!)

Comment: Everyone is encouraged for Nomination - The GIS SE (every user) community have the right to vote. That happens next week. Just 'guiding' the Nominees to write about themselves.

Comment: nice edit, seems its ok to speak freely only if you have mapperz approval.  I was only suggesting you back off so as not to appear dominating, but maybe more than just an observation was deserved.  As a moderator your position is one of responsibility not judgement, you should take on board constructive criticism rather than try to manipulate it away by editing it.

Comment: Particularly at a time of elections, editing a post with valid scrutiny of your public behavior to change the meaning is a massive conflict of interest and abuse of power. IMHO far worse than the subject of the original comment.

Comment: whuber has commented at the same rate as Mapperz. I appreciate getting insight into the various candidates' statistics.

Comment: To be precise whubar has half the rate of mapperz and between them 12 comments on just 6 candidates.  The issue of bias could arguably be interpreted as reccomendation so I could be persuaded either way on that but really I was commenting on the volume being a tad overwhelming. I do see some value in highlighting the additional information though.

Comment: Pretty sure none of the moderators get paid for this. This is a community effort, and the moderators are as much a part of the community as anyone. Obviously since they participated in the last election they have some insights into how the nominees/candidates could improve their chances of being elected and are simply providing encouragement and advice. I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: James, I appreciate your position and share your concerns about the need for moderators to avoid even the appearance of an abuse of power. However, you seem a little too quick to make accusations and allegations. The edit to your answer gives it an air of balance, positive thinking, and thoughtful concern that was lacking in the initial version. It seems to me that will lead to your concerns being taken more seriously now than they would have been.

Comment: The April 2013 Election is now in 'Election Mode' please vote and good luck to all 7 candidates.

Comment: 2013 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection - http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/2013-moderator-election-qa-question-collection 48hrs to post a Question